# Adding constraint in the column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, check-constraints

I am facing issue adding constraint to the column of table in oracle-
The column is defined with the datatype char(500 char).
I need to put the constraint which allows only the digits and N/A value to be inserted in the column.

Comment: Please edit the question with, what you tried and the issue that you are facing

Answer (score 1):

From this article stack overflow article:
[Oracle 11g - Check constraint with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621568/oracle-11g-check-constraint-with-regex)
you can see that regex works on check constraints.

A regex which supports what you want would be:

```
^([0-9]+|N/A)$
```

`^` at start of expression means start of line/row/text;
`[0-9]+` digits 1 to x;
`|` or operator;
`N/A` a specific text;
`$` end of line/row/text

Comment: Thanks ... But this regex is allowing me to insert other charaters as well :(

Comment: I got a problem testing it right now. But i guess i missed the boundaries from where to where the string has to be found. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
 CHECK (column IN (REGEXP_LIKE(column, '^[[:digit:]]{9}$'), 'N/A')
```