# SQL constraint capital letter

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

How do I create a constraint that expects the string to start with a capital letter followed by lower case letters, e.g Peter

I know how to do full uppercase

```
NAME        VARCHAR2 (12)   CONSTRAINT NAME_chk CHECK name = UPPER (name)
```

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) might be worth a read :-)

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Martin - Oracle pl/sql

Comment: this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621568/oracle-11g-check-constraint-with-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer i've worked out is to use the Initcap function

So

```
FNAME            VARCHAR2 (15) CONSTRAINT Name_ck CHECK (fname=initcap (fname))
```

Comment: but why? handle casing application side rather than database side otherwise you might cause yourself some major headaches later on