# DQL How to make item_ID have a letter at the start?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out how to get an item code/product code to have a letter fixed to the start each time I create a new product.

For example, if the product code is `A1234` the person *cannot* change the letter `A`, but they can change the last 4 numbers.

`PRODUCT_CODE` must have 5 characters (the first being `A` and the rest numbers)

How can I create a constraint on the `Product_code` column such that it must begin with `A` and end in four numbers (if it is not in this format, and is it possible to do it with a where clause? Thanks

Comment: Are you just wanting this to be a constraint on the column or are you wanting this to be an auto_incrementing field?

Comment: Sounds like a `Check` constraint, incl. regex? Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7621734/2654498) could help?

Comment: just to be a constraint

Answer (score 0):

This constraint would enforce your example:

```
create table t1 (product_code varchar2(5));

alter table t1 add constraint product_code_fmt
   check (regexp_like(product_code,'A[[:digit:]]{4}'));
```

Comment: Hi thank you i dont suppose you know if its possible or better yet how to do it via WHERE condition ?

Comment: You can't enforce a constraint with a where clause. If you don't like the check constraint, you could use a table trigger.