# add a check constraint for the column

Tags: oracle, ddl, check-constraints

Add a check constraint for the column, ONLY insert the values that didn't have any special characters except comma, space, full-stop and number in them?

For example allows like: `Group Co.,Ltd`

Should not allow `¿Abc` is important

Comment: You can use regular expressions in check constraint. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621568/oracle-11g-check-constraint-with-regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle 11g - Check constraint with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621568/oracle-11g-check-constraint-with-regex)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below example-

```
ALTER TABLE EMP ADD ( CONSTRAINT CC_NAME CHECK (TRIM(TRANSLATE(UPPER(ename),' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_,.',' ')) is null));
```

Comment: Thank you but it working only  string and blank space " Ram kanaka 123 bb.," not allows (i.e comma, full-stop and number not considering )please help me.

Comment: V. V.  Hangzhou ram. also not considering .. as per my requirement it should be considerable..Please help..Thanks in Advance

Comment: It works. Make sure you don't have any other check constraint on same and also verify if there is any validation code written in trigger.

Comment: I have updated the code and added trim now check if this works for you.

Comment: Your welcome! please mark the answer helpful and correct.