# How to i add a check constraint that only allows A-Z for the last character

Tags: database, oracle, constraints, ddl, alter

Hi i have a varchar column which i want to only allow character from A-Z on the last character. I have tried multiple solutions but it didn't work. The last one i tried was

```
ALTER TABLE timetableslot
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_RoomNo CHECK (roomNo NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]');
```

But i still can add values like asdd1 into it. Is there a way around this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you seen: [Oracle 11g - Check constraint with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621568/oracle-11g-check-constraint-with-regex) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ASCII()` function together with `SUBSTR()` :

```
ALTER TABLE timetableslot
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_RoomNo CHECK (ASCII(SUBSTR(roomNo,-1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=24790033d0cc3d1fe8f264baf24a3aaf)</kbd>

where ASCII value for A is 65, for Z it is 90, and all other capitals stay in this range.

Comment: Why `ASCII()`? Why not just use `CHECK ( SUBSTR(roomNo,-1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z' )`? Then everyone looking at the check constraint knows what it was intended to do and doesn't have to go and consult an ASCII table to check if 90 is `Z` or `[`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4c61d4e08de945dd57d4a42d23ff5eb9)

Comment: Yes, that might be as another option @MT0 .

Answer (score 1):

`regexp_like()` is a simple solution:

```
ALTER TABLE timetableslot ADD CONSTRAINT
    CHK_RoomNo CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(roomNo, '[A-Z]$') );
```

Comment: thanks this works, does the dollar sign means last character? what if i want to check the second last character, would it be $$?

Comment: @aalang perhaps a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm) is appropriate?