# Want to create a database column with following checks on oracle database sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Column should follow below validation needs to be implemented with constraints in oracle db

1. Should Be Only in Upper Case
2. Should Not Contain Leading and Trailing Spaces
3. Should Not Contain Extra Spaces Other Than One Space Between The Words
4. Should Not Contain Special Characters and Numbers Anywhere in The Text

Comment: Column data should follow the above mentioned constraints

Comment: Give it a try. If you run into problems you can ask a specific question here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621568/oracle-11g-check-constraint-with-regex

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains no effort, seems like dumped homework.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (col  varchar2(20),
  3     --
  4     constraint ch1_upper check (col = upper(col)),
  5     --
  6     constraint ch2_letraspc check (col = trim(col)),
  7     --
  8     constraint ch3_wrdspc check (regexp_like(col, '^ *(\w+ ?)+ *$')),
  9     --
 10     constraint ch4_spec check (regexp_like(col, '^[[:alpha:] ]+$'))
 11    );

Table created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into test values ('abc');
insert into test values ('abc')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH1_UPPER) violated


SQL> insert into test values (' DEF');
insert into test values (' DEF')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH2_LETRASPC) violated


SQL> insert into test values ('DEF ');
insert into test values ('DEF ')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH2_LETRASPC) violated


SQL> insert into test values (' DEF ');
insert into test values (' DEF ')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH2_LETRASPC) violated


SQL> insert into test values ('GHI23');
insert into test values ('GHI23')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH4_SPEC) violated


SQL> insert into test values ('GHI#');
insert into test values ('GHI#')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH4_SPEC) violated


SQL> insert into test values ('GHI   JKL');
insert into test values ('GHI   JKL')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH3_WRDSPC) violated


SQL> insert into test values ('GHI JKL    MNO');
insert into test values ('GHI JKL    MNO')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH3_WRDSPC) violated


SQL> insert into test values ('GHI JKL MNO');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I want do this without regex.